# How to make a benzyl position more electrophilic?

Tags: organic-chemistry

I have to write a synthesis (just below) of a molecule and propose reactants and conditions :
[image]

But I have a problem with the 2nd step. Where I need to do the ether.
[image]

Apparently it's very difficult to deprotonate the H of the allylic alcohol, so I can't use NaH on it and then react it with the nitrobromobenzene.

Instead, I have to activate the electrophily of the C next to the Br and I really don't know how can I do.

[image]

---

My proposition is that I can reduce the bromobenzene by using the NADH and reductase so I can have an NH2 and then by delocalization I can have a very electrophilic position where the alcohol can react and I will use a base like NEt3 to deprotonate. I am not very sure about that....

Comment: Who says it is hard to deprotonate allyic alcohols? Your main problem appears to be that you have a diol and no way of distinguishing between the two -OH groups.

Comment: @Waylander thank you for your reply but it is like in the 3rd picture (that I just added)

Comment: Do you have to use the p-nitrobenzyl bromide? A better route starts with p-nitrobenzyl alcohol

Answer (score 3):

Take your starting hydroxy ester (preferably methyl ester) and form a sulfonate by reaction with tosyl/mesyl chloride.

React this material with the anion of 4-nitrobenzyl alcohol (NaH/DMF) to form the ether. This is strongly favoured as the sulfonate is reactive as it is allylic.

Isolate this product then reduce the ester group with lithium borohydride in ether containing 1eq of MeOH as described [here](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/jo00371a017). This will selectively reduce the ester to the alcohol (leaving the aromatic nitro group untouched) which can then be reacted with the phosphonyl chloride.